# MySQL - not updating the updated_at column

Tags: mysql

I have a table schema defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `updated_tables` (
  `table_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP(6)  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_name`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `table_name_UNIQUE` (`table_name` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM citadel_test.updated_tables;
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`) VALUES ('testone') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `table_name`=VALUES(`table_name`);
```

After it is run, the entry **testone** is created, also updated_at is created as well with appropriate **timestamp(6).**
All good so far.

Now, when I run this query again, my expectation is to update the updated_at with new values from timestamp(6). But it does not happend. Values that are created for the first time, are never updated.

Something I need to change in my table schema, but I do not know what.

Comment: Try with this -  `updated_at TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Still does not update the timestamp(6) field.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` this should work when update query happening only

Comment: Remove TIMESTAMP length and try. It ll work

Comment: I need those values, since this is cache table. Also, simply removing it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values that are created after the first time are never updated because your next insert is not updating any field of the row at all. Since, there is no change happening in database row , so no change in `updated_at` field.

If you only want to test update timestamp feature, you can modify your table with one more field and then try it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `updated_tables` (
  `table_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` INT(3) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP(6)  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_name`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `table_name_UNIQUE` (`table_name` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The below insert is first setting status as 1 and then updating it to 2.
Since an actual update on field of row is happening, your `updated_at` will also be changed.

```
SELECT * FROM updated_tables;
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`, `status`) VALUES ('testone', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status`=VALUES(`status`);
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`, `status`) VALUES ('testone', 2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status`=VALUES(`status`);
```

Comment: Wish there is another way without introducing another field.

Comment: You can set default value for status say 1.

And change insert like :
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`) VALUES ('testone') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status`= -status;