# MySQL not executing CURRENT_TIMESTAMP updates as expected

Tags: mysql

After lots of research and several similar questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245247/mysql-not-updating-the-updated-at-column), I have reached some conclusions, but as always it is, there are more questions.

This concerns the [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Assuming the **explicit_defaults_for_timestamp** is turned off, this will work:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `updated_tables` (
  `table_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP(6)  NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_name`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `table_name_UNIQUE` (`table_name` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And the query:

```
INSERT INTO `updated_tables` (`table_name`,`updated_at`) VALUES ('products',NULL) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `table_name`=VALUES(`table_name`), `updated_at`=VALUES(`updated_at`);
```

First time the query is sent, the table is populated with 'products' and with the current time stamp.
If I repeat the query, then the field 'updated_at' is updated. Per definition, when I send NULL value, even though it is not allowed, the MySQL will update the column. 
All is fine, and works as expected.

Lets assume I turn on the **explicit_defaults_for_timestamp**
If I user the above query, it will complain the the NULL is not allowed, which complies with the rules.

Question is, how can I have the same functionality with the **explicit_defaults_for_timestamp** turned on?
There is the solution to introduce additional column (varchar) which holds for example timestamp in miliseconds. And when I update it, then the MySQL updates the updated_at accordingly.
But it looks like an overkill, I might as well update the updated_at manually. I would like to move that responsibility to MySQL level, not doing it programatically.

In short, how can I perform updates on the table_name, and have the updated_at being set properly. The trick here is I have many updates (cache table), but actually never changing the table_name value at all.

Is it possible? Or I must turn off explicit_defaults_for_timestamp?

Is it bad decision to turn it off? Looking at this [AWS RDS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=132676) post seems it is ok, but I am not sure.

Side question:

If I decide to perform updates on my own, what would be the way to construct it?
Currently the MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) has this construct:
**2018-07-10 11:32:43.490100**
How could I create same construct with Javascript? First thing coming to my mind is to get current Date, and append to it last 6 digits of current timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a trigger on INSERT and always set the value for `updated_at` with the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - the cleanest approach but this may slow down your updates. Programmatically setting the column value would be faster than firing a trigger.

If you are executing your queries from Node.js then you can use `new Date().getTime()` to get a Unix timestamp in milliseconds and then construct your query like this

```
UPDATE tbl SET col_1 = val_1, col_2 = val_2, updated_at = FROM_UNIXTIME(js_milliseconds / 1000) 
WHERE id = desired_id
```